# Google's point of view to SSL - Do I need to force HTTPS protocol for all pages on website

Tags: seo, google, https, security

Well now that google clearly declared that SSL would positively affect seo I want to know in which of the following conditions I fully benfit from ssl:

1.If I server https connection for all pages of my site but not force the users to use https (if a user type address without https will be served with http and otherwise with https connection)

2.I server https connection for all my pages but only force https connection on login , signup and other pages that needs secure connection

3.Just force https connection (all http connections will be redirected to related https page)

**What I mean from these 3 question is that I want to know that just having https connection available for all my pages is enough (and user may or may not use it) or I just have to force https connection and say good bye to http connection**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will not approach your questions head-on. Instead, I will explain a bit so that you will understand the whole Google SSL thing better. Here we go.

A fair majority of all of the metrics that dictate performance in the SERPs are domain related- meaning that in the database, the metric is relationally linked to the domain and not to a page or other site element. Well over half of these metrics are within the trust realm. In trust networks, not always having anything to do with communications networks, trusted entities can trust each other using recognized signatures and a known challenge and response pattern. SSL is the only such trust signature scheme on the web. The reason for this is simple. The Internet is a network founded upon trust and openness. SSL adds one measure of trust in a network not designed to trust. Therefore, any site that has a valid SSL certificate gets a gold star next to it's domain name and any site that has a high quality SSL certificate issuer gets a higher grade than one that does not.

End of story. Sorta.

It is only the fact that a site has a certificate and the quality of that certificate that is important. However, as Google tends to do from time to time, it wants to force it's will upon the Internet for our own good. Granted, Google thinks that we would all be better off if web traffic was secure and cannot be eaves dropped upon. While in part they are right, Google is not in the position to write the rules. Their proverbial wrists have been slapped a few times and they are a bit shy of Mother Superior. It is Google's opinion that you should only serve content up with encryption, however, it is also your right not to and you should not be punished as a result. And remember that not all content and content readers really need to be protected this way.

So what does this mean?

It means that if you have a valid certificate from a high quality issuer, and Google can see that by your offering content via SSL, then Google can and will trust you a bit more. It is a domain trust metric. Nothing more. Nothing less. A gold star and a grade. How you serve your content is up to you as long as Google can see that you have a certificate and that it is valid and good.

Lastly, for future readers, does this mean your site needs SSL? No! Absolutely not! The effect of just one trust metric is small. It is the total trust score that a domain has that counts. For example, site age can weigh more that any certificate. Put the two together, then you just might have something providing you have been well behaved all these years. Simple truth.

Comment: Every webhost just needs to have an automatic Certbot checkbox that is enabled by default. Hosts and web host software, like Apache, could be configured to serve only https by default. They could then have an option to buy an "Enhanced Certificate" but regular https would be free and automatic. https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

Comment: @HackSlash I agree this would be a good feature for control panels, however, these nicities tend to go slow. Why? Because historically many users were hands on and experienced while more and more these days users are not. A while ago this may not have been practical or even possible, but it should be today. Cheers!!