# How does SSL certificate effect Google Indexing Ranking?

Tags: web-development, https, security-certificate

I have Bought 2 SSL certificate one Basic and One Premium

The basic one will just give me `https://example.com`

The Premium will also giving me https and a Greebar in URL displaying the Company Name

Will implementing SSL would make any difference to my Google SEO ranking?
And will the result be any different if By Implementing the premium one rather than the basic one

Comment: Sorry but there is already a number of questions and answers regarding SSL SEO benefits from Google. If your looking for an 'exact increase' you won't get one because its apart Google's Algorithm which has more factors than sun creams.

Comment: Your welcome :)

Comment: You might want to read this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81022/googles-point-of-view-to-ssl-do-i-need-to-force-https-protocol-for-all-pages/81025#81025 It explains how SSL is a factor and what level of impact it has. It is a bit misleading to say that Google ranks SSL sites higher when in fact, it may make a difference or it may not make a difference and just using SSL for rank is a bit of a panacea that can disappoint.